# Home automation/AI - welcome message

Tags: home-automation

This is a home automation/AI project that I am currently figuring out details for, and currently I'm trying to figure out a way that i can detect which direction someone is walking through a door so that if someone is walking into the room the "AI" would play a welcome message, and if they were leaving the room it would play a goodbye message.

The only thing I can think of to be able to do this is to use 2 sensors such as laser break sensors or ultrasonic sensors which will use the information of one being tripped before the other one to determine which direction the person is going, a problem I can see with this though is the actual door tripping one of the sensors

Comment: What is your specific EE design question?

Comment: Is there a single sensor or something that can do this or will I have to use two sensors

Answer (score 0):

Either the two sensors or some sort of computer vision system.

It would have a bit more of an "AI" flavour, and can tell you which direction someone's facing. Simple systems can identify which way people and objects are moving in an image. More complex ones can identify the person, so you can say "Hello Dave" and so on.

Comment: do you know of any computer vision systems diy or pre-built that would allow me to do this?